# How to bind a WPF CollectionItem's element's Visible state to its collection index?

Tags: wpf, binding, styles

Assume that the below XAML is a `Style` applied to a `Path` that is a visual element of an item data template for a collection, I want to bind to the collection in such a way that if this is the first element of a collection, the path is collapsed.  How can I go about doing this?

```
<Style x:Key="PathStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
   <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Value="0" Binding="{Binding Index}">
         <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
      </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Don't think its possible without wrapping the Path in some kind of indexed collection-- `for(int i = 0;i < Paths.Length; i++) yield return new PathIndex{ Index = i++, Path = p};` then you can use a DataTrigger on {Binding Index}.

Comment: There has to be an easier way, tho I'd be willing to bind this collection to a viewmodel.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of readability, I'd use a view model, but you should also be able to use a `RelativeSource` in [`PreviousData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesourcemode.previousdata.aspx) mode:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource PreviousData}}" Value="{x:Null}">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

When there is no previous data item (ie. first item in the collection), `PreviousData` will return `null`.